# Capturing screenshot in org-capture buffer

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I am planning to insert screenshot in org-capture buffer.

I have a function that can create a screenshot image in a `images` subdirectory of current directory. However, since the org-capture buffer is an indirect buffer, the `buffer-file-name` result is nil, it can not create the subdirectory directly.

So how can I get the original buffer path in org-template, save the screenshot in the `images`, and insert it to the org-capture buffer?

Of course, I can just finalize the org-capture buffer, go to the save place, and call screenshot function there. But it is kind of cumbersome, which i do not like very much. Please give me some hint if you have some idea. Thanks very much.

Comment: Can you use `(buffer-name)` instead of `buffer-file-name`?

Comment: I can get the buffer name, but still have no way to get the path to save screenshot.

Comment: Ok. I didn't understand the question. Not sure how to do this. Have you looked at https://github.com/abo-abo/org-download ? It might do what you want...

Comment: Yes, I am using (org-download-clipboard) when in org-capture, but it does not allow to paste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified the screenshot function to adapt to take a screenshot in `Org-capture` buffer.

```lisp
(defun org-insert-clipboard (&optional caption)
  (interactive "P")
  (let* ((image-dir
      (if (not (buffer-file-name))
          (let ((buffer-name (replace-regexp-in-string "CAPTURE-[0-9-]*" "" (buffer-name))))
        (concat (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name (get-file-buffer buffer-name))) "images"))
        "images")))
    (unless (file-exists-p image-dir)
      (make-directory image-dir))
    (let* ((image-file (concat image-dir "/" (format-time-string "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S") ".png"))
       (exit-status 
        (call-process"convert" nil nil nil 
             "clipboard:" image-file)))
      (if caption
      (insert (format "#+CAPTION: %s label:fig:%s\n" (read-input "Caption: ") (read-input "label: "))))
      (org-insert-link nil (concat"file:"image-file) "")
      (org-display-inline-images))))

(bind-key "C-S-y" 'org-insert-clipboard)
```

Comment: How does this function affect the (org-download-clipboard) function? I am actually using (org-download-clipboard).

Comment: This function is not working: it does not create a file, only the images folder.

Comment: Do you have imagemagick installed on your system?

Comment: Yes, I have it installed.