# Org-capture: not able to copy paste image in transient buffer

Tags: org-capture, images, copy-paste

Basically that: when I try to capture on the fly ideas with images, I can't paste them. Org-capture seems to only work for text. Any ideas on how to bypass this limitation? Thanks!

I just noted this post: [Capturing screenshot in org-capture buffer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/capturing-screenshot-in-org-capture-buffer)

Would that solve my problem?

Comment: For this use case, I would put the image path `[[PATH/a.jpg]]`. You can show inline images with `(setq org-startup-with-inline-images t)`.

Comment: I am actually using (org-download-clipboard) to paste and it won't work.